# How to disable dates in second datetimepicker based on next days in the first one

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I use the bootstrap date picker and I use two textboxes to search by date from-to, want to the second textbox give me the days after the days in the first textbox,
any help, please.

HTML :

```
<form action="{{url('search/ticket')}}" method="get">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="timepickerfrom form-control" name="remember" placeholder="Search From" id="txtStartDate" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
       <input type="text" class="timepickerto form-control" name="remember" placeholder="Search To" id="txtEndDate" required>
       <button type="submit" class="basic-button">Submit</button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

javascript :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.timepickerfrom').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    });

    $('.timepickerto').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `change` event on the input itself if you want to respond to manual input, because the `changeDate` event is only for when the date is changed using the datepicker.

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.timepickerfrom').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',

    }).on('changeDate', function(selected){

        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('.timepickerto').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    });

    $('.timepickerto').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I use the above link but it's give me the date and the time in the textbox, I want just the date only, any suggestions,<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('#txtStartDate').datetimepicker();$('#txtEndDate').datetimepicker({    useCurrent: false });
        $("#txtStartDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#txtEndDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#txtEndDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#txtStartDate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if anyone wants help.

It's called the **linked datepicker**

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers